# vscode doesn't hint when cursor in the bracket, how do i fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, when I write Python in `vscode`:

Writing `pri` can prompt `print(|)`.
But at this time, there is no prompt when inputting in the `print` parentheses. For example, `print(le|)` can't prompt `len()`.

I tried pressing `Esc` to restart the prompt and it didn't work.

What is the reason for this and how can I change it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You can try adding `"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": true` and `"editor.quickSuggestions": {"other": true, "strings": true, "comments": false}` to your `settings.json` (you may want to adjust, what you'd like to set to `true` or `false`).

Comment: emm... google translate made  a mistake     i mean until I press ESC and it can work

Comment: Thank you ~ it helps me. and what I add additional is : "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,   and it work

Comment: I am glad to hear that. Btw.: It would be nice if you'd consider to formulate an [answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others who encounter the same problem can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

> "editor.quickSuggestions": {"other": true, "strings": true,
>   "comments":    false}
>       "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": false,

add that to setting.json